# View model usage

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm about to start work on a large project using MVVM design pattern. I've worked on smaller projects in the past using MVVM, but I want to make sure my approach to MVVM is good/manageable as possible before I attempt something much larger.

The following view model is from a project that I have worked on in the past. It is a simple, functional program that I use to push releases to people within my network. When they run their programs, they fetch the latest versions from the SQL server via stored procedure. This tool is what I use to manage those files.

The program consists of 2 ListViews, one holds local program files, and the other holds server program files. Each file is represented by a DbAssembly object (even the local files). There are 2 separate context menus for the ListViews, one allows me to Upload or Delete a local file, the other allows me to push the file to beta, live or archived status, or download the file for my own use. There is also a button that runs all local files.

```
public class AssembliesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Fields
    private ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> _localAssemblies;
    private ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> _serverAssemblies;

    //Properties
    public ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> LocalAssemblies
    {
        get { return _localAssemblies; }
        private set
        {
            _localAssemblies = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LocalAssemblies");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> ServerAssemblies
    {
        get { return _serverAssemblies; }
        private set
        {
            _serverAssemblies = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ServerAssemblies");
        }
    }

    //Constructors
    public AssembliesViewModel()
    {
        InitializeCommands();
        RefreshLocalAssemblies();
        RefreshServerAssemblies();
    }

    //Methods
    private void RefreshLocalAssemblies()
    {
        LocalAssemblies = new ObservableCollection<DbAssembly>(
            VersionFinder.GetLocalVersions());
    }
    private void RefreshServerAssemblies()
    {
        ServerAssemblies = new ObservableCollection<DbAssembly>(
            VersionFinder.GetServerVersions(null));
    }
    private void RunAssemblies(Window param)
    {
        AssemblyLoader.Run();
        if (param != null) param.Close();
    }
    private void Delete(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.Delete();
        RefreshLocalAssemblies();
    }
    private void Upload(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.Upload();
        RefreshServerAssemblies();
    }
    private void Download(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.Download();
        RefreshLocalAssemblies();
    }
    private void ReleaseBeta(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.ReleaseBeta();
        RefreshServerAssemblies();
    }
    private void ReleaseLive(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.ReleaseLive();
        RefreshServerAssemblies();
    }
    private void Archive(DbAssembly param)
    {
        if (param == null) return;
        param.Archive();
        RefreshServerAssemblies();
    }

    //Commands
    private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        RefreshLocalAssembliesCommand = new RelayCommand(x => RefreshLocalAssemblies());
        RefreshServerAssembliesCommand = new RelayCommand(x => RefreshServerAssemblies());
        RunAssembliesCommand = new RelayCommand(x => RunAssemblies(x as Window));
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Delete(x as DbAssembly));
        UploadCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Upload(x as DbAssembly));
        DownloadCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Download(x as DbAssembly));
        ReleaseBetaCommand = new RelayCommand(x => ReleaseBeta(x as DbAssembly), x => CanReleaseBetaExecute(x as DbAssembly));
        ReleaseLiveCommand = new RelayCommand(x => ReleaseLive(x as DbAssembly), x => CanReleaseLiveExecute(x as DbAssembly));
        ArchiveCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Archive(x as DbAssembly), x => CanArchiveExecute(x as DbAssembly));
    }
    public ICommand RefreshLocalAssembliesCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand RefreshServerAssembliesCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand RunAssembliesCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand UploadCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand DownloadCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ReleaseBetaCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ReleaseLiveCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ArchiveCommand { get; private set; }
    private bool CanReleaseBetaExecute(DbAssembly param)
    {
        return param == null ? false
            : (param.Beta == null && param.Live == null && param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
    }
    private bool CanReleaseLiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
    {
        return param == null ? false
            : (param.Live == null && param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
    }
    private bool CanArchiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
    {
        return param == null ? false
            : (param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

One thing that I try to do is ensure code looks neat when folded, as I find that it's usually much easier to find what I'm looking for.

[image]

Please let me know of any ideas/improvements that could be made to improve my code technique.

Comment: But what does it ***do***? It helps immensely to briefly describe what the program does. It's MVVM. Okay, but that's a pattern. It's not what the program ***is***. Make sense?

Comment: @RubberDuck Apologies, I wasn't sure if the purpose of the program pertained to good application of the pattern. I've updated my question with hopefully enough information.

Comment: The application of the program is *always* important. Thank you very much much! Welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- at the setters of the `ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> LocalAssemblies` and `ObservableCollection<DbAssembly> ServerAssemblies` you should check if the collection is equal to the set value. If yes, the event shouln't be raised.
- tenary expressions can be quite helpful, but they just don't improve the readability, especially if they are used for evaluating boolean expressions. This

  > ```
  >     private bool CanReleaseBetaExecute(DbAssembly param)
  >     {
  >         return param == null ? false
  >             : (param.Beta == null && param.Live == null && param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
  >     }
  >     private bool CanReleaseLiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
  >     {
  >         return param == null ? false
  >             : (param.Live == null && param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
  >     }
  >     private bool CanArchiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
  >     {
  >         return param == null ? false
  >             : (param.Archived == null) ? true : false;
  >     }
  > ```

  can be refactored to be more readable

  ```
  private bool CanReleaseBetaExecute(DbAssembly param)
  {
      return (param != null && param.Beta == null && param.Live == null && param.Archived == null);
  }
  private bool CanReleaseLiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
  {
      return (param != null && param.Live == null && param.Archived == null);
  }
  private bool CanArchiveExecute(DbAssembly param)
  {
      return (param != null && param.Archived == null);
  }
  ```
- you should change the [order of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310967/2655508). It should be at least

  1. constructors
  2. properties
  3. methods

I don't like naming each input parameter `param` and if I see this, I assume that if you have two ore more input parameteres you will have `param1`, `param2`...

Otherwise your code looks good and tidy. You are using meaningful names for methods, properties and fields.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I found it quite helpful. I went ahead and made the changes you suggested, including changing the parameter names be more meaningful. I'm wondering if I should follow the linked code order rules for commands, as I find keeping code relating to commands in one place is very efficient... I did try grouping them in their correct categories (ICommands grouped into properties, Initialize and CanExecute methods grouped into methods), but I think it is harder to find things this way... Thank you for your help